# Google Apps script - syntax of passed in ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, custom-function

I use Google Apps Scripts to analyse some data in a Google Sheet.
I want to obtain the first date of purchase and the last date of sale of a group of tickers "Tickers" extracted from a list of tickers "TickerRange". The dates are in "dateRange".
The tickers should be included in the calculation only if the related tickbox is checked in "includeRange".
After a lot of trying, I believe there is a syntax problem in the line:

```
if (TickerRange[i] == Tickers[j]) {
```

I have also tried

```
if (TickerRange[i].value == Tickers[j].value) {
```

and still it does not work.
Here the full code:

```
function TickersDates(Tickers,TickerRange,dateRange,includeRange) {  
    var Datesoutput = new Array(1);
    // Compute StartDate and EndDate for the current tickers
    var dateTemp = new Date(1900, 01, 01);
    var minDate= new Date(2900, 01, 01);
    var maxDate= new Date(1900, 01, 01);
    for(var j=0, jLen=Tickers.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        if (includeRange[j]=="true" && Tickers[j]!="") {
            for(var i=0, iLen=dateRange.length; i<iLen; i++) {
                dateTemp = new Date(dateRange[i]);
                if (isValidDate(dateTemp)){
                    if (TickerRange[i] == Tickers[j]) {
                        minDate = Math.min(dateTemp.valueOf(), minDate.valueOf());
                        maxDate = Math.max(dateTemp.valueOf(), maxDate.valueOf());
                    }
                } 
            }   
        }           
    }    
    var StartDate = new Date(minDate)  
    var EndDate = new Date(maxDate)  
    Datesoutput[0]=StartDate
    Datesoutput[1]=EndDate
    return Datesoutput;  
}
```

Comment: Is `dateRange` a Range or an array values?

Comment: dateRange is a range of cells I pass in. A typical call for this function is from a cell:
=TickersDates(A1:A7,C:C,D:D,B1:B7)

Comment: Well `dateTemp = new Date(dateRange[i]);` doesn't make much sense because you need values.  Take a look at the documentation and read about Range.getValues();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments) of a custom function is a **2 dimensional array**. You should use

```
if (TickerRange[i][0] == Tickers[j][0]) {
```

as objects cannot be compared: `[]!==[]`